# Is there a way to specify a range of numbers as json value?

Tags: json

I have to specify a range of number as value in a json file. Right now I have set an upper and a lower limit but is there any other way to do that?

```
{
 "x_upper": 100,
 "x_lower": 90,
 "y_upper": 50,
 "y_lower": 40
}
```

Comment: Not really. You could encode as an array `{ "x_range": [90, 100], ... }`, but there is no "range" primitive in JSON if that's what you're asking. Maybe take a look at this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/298999/what-is-the-best-data-model-to-represent-mathematical-range-in-database-xml-j

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looked much better than what I had been doing

```
{
 "x": {"low": 90, "high": 100},
 "y": {"low": 40, "high": 50}
}
```